# euro sign from php to csv shows Â

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv, euro

I´m having trouble with the output to a csv file with the euro sign. i´ve tried using € which doesn´t work and the &euro which also doesn´t work. This only works in my table view but not when exported to csv.

Hopes someone could help me out.

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to say that what shows instead of the eurosign is this symbol: Â

```
'&euro;&nbsp;'
```

Comment: Oh that's a typo. Im using it with the semicolon. &#8364; doesn't work either. But thanks for the help. Do you know another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old thread but I am answering it anyway for anyone finding this thread via a search engine.

What really worked for me is the following conversion:

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $csv);
```

No encoding headers oder other conversions needed, just use the Symbol "€". This has been working since Office 2000 or earlier and still works with Office 2016/365.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would run a `utf8` encoding function on the file

Example

```
mb_convert_encoding($csv, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
```